# How to connect to remote oracle database using node js from raspberry pi 3?

Tags: node.js, oracle, odbc, raspberry-pi3

I have *node js* application running on rapsberry pi 3. I want to connect to remote oracle database. Are there any Node js odbc drivers available for raspberry pi? I have found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) but it doesn't support ARM processors.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the driver you found, or another means, to create a REST API which you can consume from the Raspberry Pi 3. Have a look at [this recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQgw2WmyuFM) for some details.